# How to make specific instance of Oracle DB case insensitive?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I would like to make specific INSTANCE of Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition CASE INSENSITIVE. Cany anyone let me know if this is possible. I already read few blogs where whole DB can be made CASE INSENSITIVE but for specific instance didn't get any idea.

Comment: Isn't it Oracle DBs case insensitive by default?

Comment: it is only to compare string of for another purpose ?

Comment: How are you defining 'database' and 'instance' here? Maybe you can add an overview of how you'd do it for a database, and how you'd want it to work for an instance - what problem you're trying to solve, for example, and how you'd choose which instance to use?

Answer (score 1):

You need to play around with `NLS_SORT, NLS_COMP` parameters. But don't directly implement in production, as you might just hit performance issues if you do not do the extra bit of work required.

I am not sure what you mean by "a specific instance". Is it a RAC environment? Do you want one of the nodes to always have case insensitive sessions?

Anyway, you can do it at `SESSION` level as well as `SYSTEM` level. But do you really want to implement the HARD way at SYSTEM level?

For example, at session level :

`SQL> alter session set nls_comp='LINGUISTIC';`

`Session altered`

`SQL> alter session set nls_sort='BINARY_CI';`

`Session altered`

At system level :

You could have a `AFTER LOGON TRIGGER` and `execute the alter session statements`. Eek, but that would be killing the performance. You will have to figure out where all you need to create case-insensitive function-based indexes. In my experience, I have always seen case-insensitive search to be slower, no matter you have the required imdex at place.

You can have a look at my article for detailed explanation, http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/oracle-case-insensitive-sorts-compares/